# Examples of UX Research Proposals

Tags: research

I'm applying for a junior-level ux research role, and I was given a brief on how the company is trying to understand the causes for user drop off on a particular page of the site. I'm being asked to construct a proposal that illustrates how I would think about the causes for drop off; how I would tackle the issue via research; and what methodologies I would draw upon and apply.

Fairly simple, but I was wondering if anyone had some concrete examples of how a ux research proposal "should" look like; ideally, what its components are; how it's typically structured, etc.

I know this is fairly general, so if anything, I can clarify.

Comment: Check out the HEART framework being used at Google Ventures. Not a complete system, but it helps formulate a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to consider the exact thing that you have been asked to write the proposal for. Then in your proposal you should consider your qualitative and quantitative design research approaches and the reason that why you are selecting those methods. Also you may require some information and live data from other teams in the company, so you should also mention those as well to make it crystal clear for all stakeholders. Writing a proposal for usability research is so tricky, you have to make sure that the proposal is not confusing for stakeholders, because as long as they are not convinced why you have those methods and what information you need to solve the issue, they cannot help you to do the research. With keeping that in mind here are some titles for chapters in the UX research proposal that depend on the size of the project you can have description for them:
- defining the problem
- history (if there is any) of similar drop issues
- mindset (what are you looking for by doing this research)
- methods (qualitative and quantitative)
- usability test sessions (one on one with users, if it is required)
- required types of information
- expected time and budget
- expected results (at least possible kind of reasons for that drop issue, you can reference to case studies)

Make sure that having this besides of your empathetic relationship with all stakeholders, can be a positive way to hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: This helps so much!

Comment: Good luck @Chris

Answer (score 1):

Did some more research, and found this to be really useful: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/26/ux-research-plan-stakeholders-love/

So if anyone would like to expand upon this particular approach, feel free to do so.

Comment: I think that rather fails to answer the 'how would you actually find out about this particular issue' question.